# How can I add multiple cell.textLabel.text in Array?

Tags: uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have make multiple selection like below in UITableViewController using. This is delegate method of UIAlertView, in which there is UIAlertView contains Table.

Now How can I add particular selected indexPath.row to my array and remove if some one uncheck it.

```
- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"MY INDEX PATH IS %@", indexPath);


if (tableAlert.type == SBTableAlertTypeMultipleSelct) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableAlert.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    else
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    [tableAlert.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to create a dictionary of your items used for the tableView. Then have a 'selected' bool property for each object in the dictionary. You can then simply turn this true or false and use `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` when your alert view is tapped. You could then also enumerate through if you needed to know which objects have their rows selected.